# HTML5 required attribute

Tags: html, required

I have the following input element in a form. When the form is submitted, I don't need a value for this field. However, when I click the submit button for the form, it gives me an error saying 'This is a required field'.

```
<input required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `required` means you **need** a value for this field.

If this value is optional, you must not use `required`.

As a side note, this is the HTML5 syntax (no value for properties, and no ending slash for autoclose tags) :

```
<input required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple remove the required tag from it completely.

Required should only be added to the html input when it IS required.

Also you do not need to specify true | false on this.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-required-attribute)